# How to create a slicer that filters information if field contains specific values?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have a column that contains text like the following:

```
Name    Type 
Mark    FT
Jess    FT; #PT
Hallon  PT
Len     FT; #PT; #HT
Tessa   PT; #HT
```

What I'm trying to do is create a slicer that has ONLY three options: FT, PT, HT
So if I choose FT, the following result would show:

```
Name    Type 
Mark    FT
Jess    FT; #PT
Len     FT; #PT; #HT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

[image]

How to achieve this?
Go to your Table, Then go to Edit queries
[image]

Then right click on Colum and duplicate it

[image]

Now right click on duplicate colum and click on split column by delimiter
[image]

Then below changes

[image]

You get something like below

[image]

Then Trim the same column
[image]

Then Replace Value
[image]

You get final Table

[image]

Go to Visualtization screen and add your column and new column and slicer you will get desired result

Comment: Cool, upvoting will make me happy as well 